# How to add user class objects to a list of objects

Tags: python

I'm trying to append objects to a list of objects, but all atrributes of the object's class are the same as the last entry

I found out that declaring the object in my for loop, fixes the problem, but don't understand why...
(It seems like all the objects in the list, reference to the same object)

## First I declare:

```
class SimpleClass:
    name = ""
simplelist = []
```

## this works:

```
for count in range(4):
    x = SimpleClass()
    x.name = count
    simplelist.append(x)
```

## this doesn't work (all values in "simplelist[].name" equal 3) - WHY?

```
x = SimpleClass()
for count in range(4):    
    x.name = count
    simplelist.append(x)
```

Comment: because you are using the same object. Move the initialization of x inside the for loop.

Comment: In your latest edit you even answer your own question. So what exactly *is* your question?

Comment: Read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x = SimpleClass()` creates [the instance of class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=class%20instance#instance-objects) (something like an object of this type).

If you run it outside the loop, you have exactly one object and try to change it. `simplelist.append(x)` in this case will append this unique object to list (and will change it each time) so you will have a list which contains many copies of one object.

If you run it inside the loop, you have several various object instantiating one class. `simplelist.append(x)` in this case will append each new object to list so you will have a list which contains many different objects.

From the official Python docs:

> Class instantiation uses function notation. Just pretend that the class object is a parameterless function that returns a new instance of the class. For example (assuming the above class):
>
> `x = MyClass()`
>
> creates a new instance of the class and assigns this object to the local variable x.
>
> The instantiation operation (“calling” a class object) creates an empty object. Many classes like to create objects with instances customized to a specific initial state.

Comment: So, _.append()_ does not create an object and copy to it, it just link-list objects I created?

Answer (score 0):

In the second case you create just one object of the class. Then you alter this object and by this all already existing copies of the object in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are creating only one object and you add it 4 times to to your list. All the objects (thus 4 times the same) will have the same value as name and this will be 3 since it is the last modification you did in the `loop`.

Answer (score 0):

In yourcase the `x` is an instance of `SimpleClass` class. Actually it is a reference/pointer and it is not changed in your `for` loop. You only change the value of `name` attribute of `SimpleClass` class. So your list will contain the same reference 3 times.